# Create a view field that contain the sum of specific fields for a specific user

Tags: views, entities

I created a content type (Donation) that contains 3 fields:

- a Donor Name field (user reference).
- a date field (for the donation month).
- the amount of the donation.

I am trying to create a view that returns a table with 2 columns:

- one for Donor Name
- one for the total/sum of all donation for that Donor.

**My question**: How can I achieve the second column (the sum of donations for the specific Donor/user) using views?

Answer (score 0):

> Try View Aggregation setting:

- Goto Advanced tab, scroll down below and set `"Use aggregation"` to
  `'Yes'`.
- Filter Your View with `Name field (user reference)`.
- Now there must be `"Aggregation settings"` inline with your field
  `"the amount of the donation"`
- Goto `"Aggregation settings"` for `"the amount of the donation"`
  field and select `'Aggregation type'` to `'Sum'`.

> Thats it, you are good to go now.